# Spring Boot Admin Parse error

Tags: spring-boot

Очень нужна инфа о работе Spring Boot Admin. В особенности о передаче ему инфы в виде xml или json. Как и где это регулируется?

Сейчас ловлю ошибку

> 4241324 2018-11-26 15:47:58,825 WARN  [ pool-1-thread-1 ] [] [,] d.c.b.a.s.SpringBootAdminRegistrator                    | Failed to register application as [id=null, url=http://host/lala-api/admin, name=lala-api] at spring-boot-admin (http://host/spring-boot-admin/api/applications): JSON parse error: Missing required creator property 'url' (index 0); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Missing required creator property 'url' (index 0)
>   at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3ad52e86; line: 1, column: 17]

Такое ощущение, что приходит  массив `[id=, url=, name=]`, должен прийти JSON `{id:, url:, name:}`  Типа он массив распарсить не может. Или я не туда смотрю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в версии библиотеки
Было:
de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:1.1.2
Стало:
de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:1.5.7

С новой версией всё работает!